# Как массово сделать загрузку файлов в базу MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mariadb, командная-строка

Имеется БД огромного формата, т.к. размер базы очень большой, база разбита на большое количество SQL файлов. Есть возможность конвертировать файлы в CSV, но опять же интересует массовая загрузка файлов в одну базу. Вопрос такой - какой командной можно массово загрузить все SQL файлы в базу из консоли?

Такой командой `-> \. C:\Users\Downloads\baza\export1.sql` поочередно загружать все файлы придется вечно. Так вот `-> \. C:\Users\Downloads\baza\` выдает ошибку. На просторах интернета вычитал, что массово файлы можно загрузить так: `"C:\Users\Downloads\baza\" | "C:\MySQL\bin\mysql.exe" -uлогин -pпароль база`, но так же не дает ни каких результатов. Еще нашел вариант массовой загрузки "на лету" из архивов 7-zip, что так же мне не подходит, так как каждый SQL файл архивировать - равносильно что в ручную загружать...

Посоветуйте команду, которой можно из папки массово загрузить SQL файлы в базу?

Comment: Какая у вас версия MySQL? Как создавались SQL файлы?

Comment: Соберите файлы в один тупым `copy C:\Users\Downloads\baza\*.sql %temp%\total.sql`, а потом грузите командой `"C:\MySQL\bin\mysql.exe" -uлогин -pпароль база < %temp%\total.sql`.

Comment: Версия 10.3.12-MariaDB, создавалась путем экспорта БД и конвертации в SQL. Общий вес базы примерно 1ТБ, получиться ли собрать файл в один без последствий? Не зря же разработчики сайта разделили базу на отдельные файлы. @Akina спасибо, буду пробовать по вашему совету.

Answer (score 1):

[Здесь](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/02/22/restore-mysql-logical-backup-maximum-speed/) отличная статья о максимизации скорости восстановления MySQL (Percona Server) из SQL дампа.

Вот главные "ускорители":

- [отключите `InnoDB DoubleWrite`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-doublewrite-buffer/): `set innodb_doublewrite=0`
- [увеличьте `max_allowed_packet`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#max_allowed_packet): `set max_allowed_packet=1G`
- [увеличьте `innodb_buffer_pool_size`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_buffer_pool_size)
- отключите проверку целостности внешних ключей: `set global FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0`
- отключите `binlog`: параметр `--skip-log-bin`
- `set innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0`

Полный набор параметров ключей командной строки, использовавшийся в статье:

```
--innodb_buffer_pool_size=4GB
--innodb_log_file_size=1G
--skip-log-bin
--innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
--innodb_io_capacity=700
--innodb_io_capacity_max=1500
--max_allowed_packet=1G
--innodb_doublewrite=0
```

Comment: Ответ весьма полезный... но он никак не соотносится с заданным вопросом.

Comment: @Akina, будем считать, что это ответ на следующий вопрос автора об ускоении загрузки дампа... ;)